# Does a Router event listener in angular 2 form some sort of closure?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, dom-events

The event listener runs whenever the route path changes, I want to run few lines of code inside the listener only when it runs the first time. I'm trying to conditionally do this.

```
.catch((error: any) => {
    console.log("inside catch block");
    this.catchFlag = true;
      this._router.events.subscribe(
          (event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                console.log("catch flag in subscription ", this.catchFlag);
                if (this.catchFlag === true) {
                    this.catchFlag = false;
                    // some code here
                }
            }
          });
      return  Observable.throw(error);
  });
```

I have the necessity of the router path when the code enters the catch block, I don't want to run the code inside the subscription when the code has not entered the catch blog but a route change event triggered it. But even for the router events, I get the value of `catchFlag` as `true`, even though I make it `false` in the very first entry. Is this how it is supposed to work? If yes, then what should be the approach to conditionally execute this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was indeed forming a closure, when the code enters into the catch block again and again.

I took a subscription variable:

```
this.routerSubscription = this._router.events.subscribe(...)
```

and I unsubscribe it whenever I enter the `.catch()`.
So the code looks something like this:

```
.catch((error: any) => {
    if (this.routerSubscription){
        this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.routerSubscription = this._router.events.subscribe(...);
    return /.../
})
```